# Asterisk (VOIP) port forwarding on TP-LINK

Tags: port-forwarding, voip, ipv4, ubuntu-16.04, asterisk

I have local Asterisk server on Ubuntu 16.04. Its address is 192.168.0.101:5060 and I would like to be allowed to talk with other users when I am outside local network. I tried this but it doesn't work. I am not good at network engineering. IS there any way to do this well?
I am using SIP.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check router for SIP ALG option(google by router model+sipalg). **DISABLE**  that.

You also have forward ports 5060, 10000-20000 udp.

On server need set nat=comedia, if you have static ip add externip=your_ip_here.